# ListItem Column Level security

Tags: list, list-view

I have a List and default view for that list. Some of List columns contain sensitive information, that should be visible for some group (SharePoint group ) of users, others shouldn't be able to see those columns.

While I have custom add/edit/view forms for my list, and could successfully handle this in List Item form pages, I can't seem to handle this on AllItems.aspx page.

Is there any **Out Of The Box** solution for my requirement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible Out Of The Box, which is why some companies sell solutions for this kind of problems, such as SharePointBoost Column/View Permission.

Comment: Tried adding link to the product, but was not able to. Probably considered advertisement

Comment: I google it, and found web site, thanks for reply.